# Does less storyboard segue and more code make the app faster/ smaller?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, segue

I have **a huge amount of storyboard segues** which let the storyboard look a little bit confusing.

To avoid this mess i want to transform some of them or rather **create them in code**. **(I already know how to do it)**

**My Question** according this process:

- Is my app faster/ smaller if I use more storyboard segue, is it faster/ smaller if I create most of the segues in code or is the speed/ size in both cases equal?

My App is written in Swift, but maybe some Objective-C developers may help me.

Comment: You can now split your Storyboards up into multiple storyboards using storyboard references. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226 have a read at this, its a bit old and he has since changed his mind http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder also `premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Code is in most cases a bit faster, as far as I know. But the difference is so small that it doesn't make a real difference.

You should use the method you are most comfortable with. I prefer code.